# Change value of form input onload then onhover, fade onclick and finally remove on type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hopefully I haven't scared away too many people with that title :-$

Using Javascript or jQuery, how can we make a form text input:

1. Show a default value/placeholder text
2. When hovered, replace the default value/placeholder text with different text
3. When clicked, fade away the different text slightly
4. And finally, when the user begins typing, remove default/placeholder text entirely

**Here are the meat and bones of this question in images:**

[image: Action #1]

This step simply places a nice default text or placeholder in the text input box. Easy peasy.

[image: Action #2]

Now, the user is hovering the input box. We'd like to give them a suggestion of what they could search for. A nice fade effect from the text in Action #1 to this text would be phenomenal.

[image: Action #3]

Here we've faded away the suggestion text, encouraging the user to type their own search terms.

[image: Action #4]

Finally, the user begins typing and the suggestion text is removed altogether.

Comment: Do you plan on supporting older browsers?

Comment: No - just the newer browser that can also support CSS3 and HTML5 stuff

Comment: What have you tried? Not sure if there's a plugin for that, but it seems to me it's just a bunch of event handlers and some logic and CSS

Comment: Well, I haven't got much so far - I'm not very proficient at Javascript at all and keep getting hung up on Action #3 (the fade out): http://jsfiddle.net/WFYmR/, haven't even tackled #2 or #4 yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just basic HTML, jQuery and CSS.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." data-placeholder-hover="Search for stuff!" />​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('input[data-placeholder-hover]').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.toggleClass('hovered');

    var temp = $this.prop('placeholder');

    $this.prop('placeholder', $this.data('placeholder-hover'))
    $this.data('placeholder-hover', temp);
});​
```

**CSS**:

```
input.hovered::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

input.hovered:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

input.hovered:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b94mb/**

You can style the textbox even more with `:focus` and other pseudo-selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/b94mb/4/

Comment: Thank you - works perfectly and gives me much more understanding of jQuery functions. Thanks again!